# How to convert string to PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following string

```
sender=48&destination=51&message=hi+good&sender=48&destination=49&message=good+boy
```

Please help me convert that into PHP array as following

```
 array = array(
     'sender'=>48,
     'destination'=>51,
     'message'=>hi+good,
     'sender'=>48,
     'destination'=>49,
     'message'=>good+boy
 );
```

***Note: Its not PHP GET.***

Comment: Its not a PHP GET. @FastSnail I failed with link you provided.

Comment: one thing I have noticed here same array key not able to come in single array. e.g : sender,message,destination 2 times

Comment: your desire output will wrong. your array should be like `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sender] => 48
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [destination] => 51
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [message] => hi+good
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sender] => 48
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [destination] => 49
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [message] => good+boy
        )

)`

Comment: and have you **tried anything** so far yourself?

Comment: I tried. I was close but following answer completed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as inteded, to solve this problem, you just need to use explode() correctly, otherwise it's easy.

Here you go :

```
$firstarr=explode('&',$yourstring);
$desiredarr=array();
foreach($firstarr as $pair)
{
    $exp_pair=explode('=',$pair);
    $desiredarr[$exp_pair[0]]=$exp_pair[1];
}

print_r($desiredarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is from query string then you can just use `$_REQUEST` otherwise you need to `explode()` string using `&` as separator. Then for each item in array that explode() generate, you split with `=` and add it to final array
or using `parse_str()`.

Comment: If I explode it comes `Array([0]=sender=48` ..

Comment: How do you call `explode()`?

Comment: $array = explode("&", $array); The key is coming in 0, 1 series.